# Why does jQuery's $.makeArray ignore string keys?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, key-value

Here's my code:

```
// My object
var fakeArray = { "length": 2, 0: "Addy", 1: "Subtracty" };

// Convert my object to a real array
var realArray = $.makeArray( fakeArray )

// Use $.map() to a
$.map( realArray, function( val, i ) {
    alert(val);
});
```

The alert gives `"Addy"` and `"Subtracty"` but completely disregards the `"length": 2` key-value pair. What's more is that when I swap `"length": 2`

```
// Swap 2 and "length"
var fakeArray = { 2: "length", 0: "Addy", 1: "Subtracty" };
```

It only alerts the object (i.e. `[object Object]`)
What gives?

Comment: Don't use alert(), use console.log() and then check your browser's console.

Comment: Just taking a stab at this one, but probably because JavaScript doesn't have associative arrays which is what a _string key_ would be. JavaScript has bracket notation and dot notation, but they are in reference to objects not arrays.

Comment: for the first case, your `realArray` is actually an array so the `length` property becomes ***non-iterable***, you ***can't*** use any loop of any kind (even `for...in`) to make it expose, the only way to expose that property is using pure JS method called `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()`. For the second case, if you swap 2 and "length" then the `fakeArray` is not a fake array at all, so it can't be converted to a real array using `$.makeArray`, hence the whole `fakeArray` is put into an array such as `[fakeArray]`, alerting it only shows `[object Object]`.

Comment: Thanks @KingKing 
Another thing I noticed is that when I change `"length": 2` to `"length": 3` it returns `[object Object]` again, why is that?

Comment: @Wilhelm that's also a condition for an object to be array-like object, the `length` should be the number of items of the array, you have `0` and `1` so it should be `length:2`. Anyway that is how `$.makeArray` understands an object to be array-like and convert it to the real array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because [`$.makeArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/) is supposed to work on **array-like objects**.

An object with a `.length` property<sup>1</sup> will be iterated from `0` to `length`, and each property value will be pushed onto the result array. Non-integer keys will coherently be ignored by this.

All other objects will simply be wrapped in an array.

```
> $.makeArray({"length": 2, 0: "Addy", 1: "Subtracty"})
["Addy", "Subtracty"]
> $.makeArray({0: "Addy", 1: "Subtracty", 2: "length"})
[{0: "Addy", 1: "Subtracty", 2: "length"}]
```

<sup>1: for exact definition see [`isArrayLike`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/ca0086b55a158d8a4347f94254878d6dc5dd90ed/src/core.js#L481)</sup>

Comment: What does `( length - 1 ) in obj` in `isArrayLike`'s final return check for?

Comment: That `1` [is a property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) of your object with length `2`.

Comment: I see. So, `in` essentially checks the indices to confirm if an `object` or (`array`) isn't empty? I didn't know JS had an `in` operand. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: Not all indices, only the last one. It would still allow half-empty "sparse" array(-like object)s. But yes, it looks like this test should prevent empty objects (that have a `length` property by accident) from being identifed as array-like.